# is the sentence in the main body grammatically correct?

Tags: participle

"Sprechen ist voll gesehen: sich aussprechendes mit einem Anderen über etwas Sprechen."

I would expect "aussprechend" in place of "aussprechendes" here. Is the sentence, as it stands, grammatically correct? If so, what part of speech is "aussprechendes" and what exactly is its grammatical function in this sentence?

Comment: This "sentence" doen't make any sense. Aside from that the capitalization is totally mixed up.

Comment: Smells like Heidegger.

Comment: Please add the source and some context to the quote. Otherwise it looks like gibberish. If you are the source, please add in english what you want to express.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: as far  as I understand that PDF, it is Heidegger: https://www.fernuni-hagen.de/philosophie/docs/kap5.pdf -> maybe it is "M. Heidegger: Der Begriff der Zeit (Vortrag 1924).- In: ders.. Gesamtausg. LXIV. Frankfurt a. M. 2004, p. 105-125, hier p. 113., ", maybe it is "Cf. auch schon Hegel, der Sprache als Mitte, freilich als – durch Reflexion – sich „zersetzende Mitte“ verstand. G. W.F. Hegel:
Werke III, p. 378."

Comment: googling around says it is "M. Heidegger: Der Begriff der Zeit (Vortrag 1924)", page 113, contexts p.112f: it is point 3 from "Grundstrukturen des Daseins", which is "3. Miteinander in der Welt sein"

Answer (score 3):

Going by the ending *-es*, *aussprechendes* is an attributive adjective modifying the nominalised verb *Sprechen*.

> sich aussprechendes Sprechen

The grammar isn't the problem. One wonders what the intended meaning is.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is confusing and hard to understand but this sort of language is typical for certain German philosophers (Heidegger was already mentioned in the comments).

The sentence is grammatically correct if one reads "sich aussprechendes" as the accusative object of "Sprechen".

Another option is to read "sich aussprechendes" as an attribute of "Sprechen", as proposed by David Vogt. This option may make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Are we analyzing some 19th century philosophy treatise for grammar here, by any chance ? Caveat: this way madness lies ;-)

Anyway, holding this text to standards of 21th century grammar and usage:

> I would expect "aussprechend" in place of "aussprechendes" here

So would I.

> Is the sentence, as it stands, grammatically correct?

No. "aussprechendes" is wrong.

Additional nitpicks:

One would not write "mit einem Anderen" but "mit einem anderen" ( ".. Menschen" is implied, therefore lowercase)

"über etwas Sprechen" is also wrong.
Either it is an infinitive phase and lowercase

- "Wir müssen über etwas sprechen"

or the verb is meant to be used as a noun, in which case one would concatenate and capitalize the qualifiers

- "das Über-Etwas-Sprechen"

Oh, and

> voll gesehen

Not incorrect as such, but .. yeah ... no. You would not hear that in a conversation.